# Interactive PDF in InDesign - showing a form area after selecting from dropdown menu

Tags: pdf, interactive, adobe-indesign

I am trying to show a form area after selecting an option from dropdown menu. For example, if my dropdown menu options were ONE, TWO, and THREE, I would like the option THREE to take them to another area of the form and also show that area when it is selected. I would want the same thing for each of the dropdown options, but going to three different areas. (This question on the form helps the user decide which part of the second section of the form they need to fill out.) Is this possible with an InDesign interactive PDF?

Thanks for any shared knowledge in this area!

Answer (score 0):

It might be worthwhile to reconsider the workflow. The issue is that (the way I understand it) as soon as the user has made a choice, he will forcibly get to that particular area. Such a process is not considered Best Practice, because it interferes seriously with the way the user may work.

Normally it is recommended to add an additional active element (aka Button or Link) which gets the user to that particular area. So, it is the user's choice to continue filling in that area, or go to it later.

A means to prevent the user from unnecessarily filling sections (which may actually lead to rejects by the receipient of the filled form), would be to clear the non-relevant sections and make the according fields read-only or inaccessible.

Anyway, for the actual action, you might better add it in Acrobat. The easiest would be a Button where you select the Go to Page View action, where you can be quite precise with the view the user will be transferred to.

Comment: In this particular case, the answer to this question takes them to the appropriate area that they need to fill in to complete the form. Everyone has to fill in a section one and section two, but there are three different kinds of section two based on the answer to this question. The user will not need to ever see the other options of section two.

They will use the form electronically and so will the receivers of the form. It is part of a job request workflow until we are able to get this incorporated into our custom software version - a year or so down the road.